# Vim Create File(s) Using Template(s)

Tags: vim

I'm tending to rely on vim more than a full IDE for working on projects, and one of the things I find myself doing on a regular basis is creating a new file(s) with derived values.

For example, creating a new c++ class involves creating a `.hpp` file and a `.cpp` file, adding file comments, the license, the author, ctor/dtor, copy, assign, move, etc...

## .hpp

```
class %Object% {

public:

    explicit %Object%() = default;
    ~%Object%() = default;

    %Object%(%Object%&& rhs) = default;
    %Object%(const %Object%& rhs) = default;
    %Object%& operator=(%Object%&& rhs) = default;
    %Object%& operator=(const %Object%& rhs) = default;

protected:

private:

}
```

## .cpp

```
#include "%Object%.hpp"
```

Another example would be a `.h` and a `.c` file in c.

I'm a little familiar with [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and [muTemplate](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template), which both seem to cut down on boilerplate a lot.  However, I'm not clear if there's a way to use these, or something else, outside of a file scope.  I wrote a really quick and dirty set of bash [scripts](https://github.com/uxcn/new) to do it, and I'm getting ready to re-implement it in python, but I'd rather use an existing plugin.

Is there a way to do this with UltiSnips, muTemplate, or something else?  If not, is there a good way to extend an existing plugin?

Answer (score 1):

*Discl.* I'm the maintainer of mu-template and lh-cpp. Unfortunately I'm just seeing your question now -- I would say that you shouldn't have hesitated to drop me an email/an issue/... I'm not sure the question is still opened. I'm not even sure to have exactly grasped what you were looking for.

Since the version you've experimented with, I've added many templates/snippets/wizards in lh-cpp to generate [classes according to their semantics](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/snippets.md#class-patterns). You can now either:

- expand things like `value-class`, `base-class`, etc
- or call a function to expand the same wizard/snippet/template and give it parameters. For instance, expanding a value class with a pointer-like parameter will trigger the generation of the copy constructor and assignment operator (otherwise, they would be defaulted, explicitly or implicitly depending on options and on the C++ flavour detected (C++98/03, C++11 or more -- [rule of all or nothing](http://arne-mertz.de/2015/02/the-rule-of-zero-revisited-the-rule-of-all-or-nothing/) still has to be enforced). Alas this approach is not very ergonomic at the moment. I have to find a way to simplify this task. You can find example of use in the [test/spec directory of lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/tree/master/spec).

Note that the c++ template for C++ files are also highly customizable -- on a per project basis. [Usual licence texts](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template/tree/master/after/template/license/text) are ready to include. A new C++ file knows how to include its associated header file (if detected).

Comment: Thanks :).  I hadn't seen lh-cpp yet.  This is closer to what I ultimately had in mind, but not entirely there.  I honestly haven't had any time to think about this for a while.  I definitely want to re-visit the scripts I originally wrote in some shape or form though (ugly, ugly hacks).  The biggest things I'm hoping for are a solution that's as simple and orthogonal as possible, supporting the concept of objects encompassing files and/or directories.

Comment: @Jason, this may not be the best place to discuss this, and I'm not sure what you mean by "encompassing files and/or directories". In case your need is still there, don't hesitate to drop me a mail or use the trackers to see how lh-cpp can be used to fit your needs. Regarding the simplicity of use, I still have the last point of https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/TODO.md#other-snippets to take care of.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to one of your start up file:

```
" Function to substitute the class names in a file
function! SubstituteClassName()
   execute "1,$s/%Object%/" . expand("%:t:r") . "/g"
endfunction

" Function to create the skeleton of a header file
function! CreateHeaderFile()
  1
  insert
#pragma once
#ifndef %Object%_H
#define %Object%_H

class %Object% {

public:

    explicit %Object%() = default;
    ~%Object%() = default;

    %Object%(%Object%&& rhs) = default;
    %Object%(const %Object%& rhs) = default;
    %Object%& operator=(%Object%&& rhs) = default;
    %Object%& operator=(const %Object%& rhs) = default;

protected:

private:

}
.
  call SubstituteClassName()
endfunction

" Function to create the skeleton of a source file
function! CreateSourceFile()
  1
  insert
#include "%Object%.hpp"
.
  call SubstituteClassName()
endfunction

function! CreateClassFiles(name)

  " Open the header file.
  execute "edit " . a:name . ".hpp"
  " Create the skeleton of the header file
  call CreateHeaderFile()
  " Write the file
  wa

  " Open the source file.
  execute "edit " . a:name . ".cpp"
  " Create the skeleton of the header file
  call CreateSourceFile()
  " Write the file
  wa

endfunction
```

Now you can create the skeleton .hpp and .cpp files using

```
call CreateClassFiles("myclassname")
```

Comment: The included code is just an example.  I already have bash [scripts](https://github.com/uxcn/new) which will do this for c/c++, bash, haskell, java, python, etc...  I was hoping something a bit more generic exists.